# Two View Controllers, shared data

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uitextview, view, sharing

I have two View controllers (A,B). I have a button on A that uses a push segue to transition to B. Both A and B are being managed within a single Navigation View Controller.

Ok. I have a UITextView in A and a UILabel in B. I want the user to enter some information into the UITextView in A, press the button, transition to B and have that information show up in the UILabel in B. Essentially I want the data in A and B to be accessible to each other.

I thought I could get away with having a single header and implementation file governing A and B and just access the data from within those files, but alas it's not working. If I move the UILabel from B back over to A then I can easily mirror the UITextView input into the UILabel......but if I move the label back over to B nothing happens (the label never changes). Everything builds and runs....just the label never changes.

I'm fearing that I'm going to have to do something exotic. I've done some programming before but I'm completely new to iOS development and Obj-C.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.